# Determinate the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ where a is an algebraic complex number over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

I have the following exercise as homework, but is harder than i thought. There is a well know answer to this question?.

Suppose that $a$ is an algebraic complex number over $\mathbb{Q}$, prove that $\sqrt{a}$ is algebraic, and determine its minimal polynomial.

Comment: Welcome to the site. To avoid any mishaps I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). When asking questions closely tied to homework assignments, the expectation is that questions should be accompanied by your own thoughts and/or other relevant context. In this case examples of cases where the procedure in Wuestenfux's answer fails would make a nice addition (given that you clearly are aware of the possibility).

Comment: This may feel unnatural in the sense that you may think it distracts from the question. However, we developed this policy because students copy/pasting their homework, asking for copy/pastable answers, presses the wrong buttons (and gives the site a bad reputation). Please take the measures to avoid giving the impression that you copy/paste assignments. Your questions will be much more warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is a zero of $f(x) = c_n x^n+\ldots+c_1x+c_0$ over $\Bbb Q$, then
$\sqrt a$ is a zero of $f(x^2)$, since $f((\sqrt a)^2) = f(a)=0$.

Comment: All that remains is the ability to test if $f(x^2)$ is irreducible. Any thoughts on that? :-)

Comment: Yes, i have no trouble with that part. Finding the minimal polynomial is where i am stuck.

Comment: When $\sqrt{a}$ is rational, the minimal polynomial is of degree 1, and there are cases  where minimal polynomial of $a$ and $\sqrt{a}$ have same degree and  $x$ has some odd exponents

Comment: For example when $a=(1+\sqrt2)^2=3+2\sqrt2$, the polynomial $f(x^2)$ is not irreducible, because $\sqrt{a}$ also generates a quadratic extension, but $f(x^2)$ is quartic.

Comment: Summary: This recipe gives the minimal polynomial if and only if $\sqrt{a}\notin\Bbb{Q}(a)$.

Comment: I think that If $a=\sqrt[3]{2}+i$ then, the minimal polynomial is $x^6+3x^4-4x^3+3x^2+12x+5$ but for $a^2$, the minimal polinomial is $x^6+6x^5+15x^4+12x^3+135x^2-114x+25$ and $a\notin Q(a^2)$. Is that correct ?